# Is that possible to switch display to "Projector only"?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

There is a possibility to choose "Projector only" mode for dual monitors in Windows OS. Is there the same with Mac OS? I need this mode to watch movies from my flat TV. It has an issue of colors distortion if laptop is not in "Projector only" mode. Thank you very much for any help.

It is MacBook Pro with Lion on board.

Comment: What kind of Mac do you have? If you have a laptop and external mouse and/or keyboard, you can just close the lip, awake the computer again, and it'll only use the external screen, or projector in this case.

Comment: No, I don't have external equipment.

Comment: I've found an external mouse, how to awake it? The laptop goes sleep when I close the lip, if I click the mouse it wokes up for a seconds and then goes to sleep again.

Comment: It shouldn't go to sleep again – is the external projector working if you awake it? Can you see your desktop or any output? (By the way @DanielBeck isn't clamshell mode working differently now since OS X Lion? If you close the lid while an external display is attached, it won't sleep the MacBook, but instead just turn off the internal display. It used to sleep the device ≤ 10.6 and require a click to wake up)

Comment: @slhck I thought I'd noticed that as well, but I rarely switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely [disable the internal display](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/14/disable-the-internal-screen-on-a-macbook-pro-or-air-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/) changing the NVRAM boot arguments using the [`nvram(8)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/nvram.8.html) command. Enter this in a terminal:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="iog=0x0"
```

Then reboot. This setting can be undone with:

```
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

Of course, your mileage may vary depending on whether the projector is recognized on startup or not. In case you screw up, you can also reset the PRAM by holding <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on a reboot.

Comment: To many efforts just to watch a movie.

Comment: I agree. In windows its just Win+P to change and its incredibly easy. I don't want to go fussing with sudo commands just to change my display configuration.